# Porting of JavaScript game engine to iOS platform

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I already have a fully working engine, written entirely in JavaScript and I want to deploy this to iOS games. The problem is that iOS does not let JavaScript control the HTML5 audio tag so no sounds can be played. As well as this, mobile devices do not work at high-performance using the HTML5 canvas element.
Can i make JavaScriptCore from webkit to be compiled into a separate library that can be used in an iOS app so that my game engine can run inside JavaScritpCore and make calls from JavaScript to the iOS app. By making calls from JavaScript to iOS, my engine can control the output of OpenGL and OpenAL so that my engine can use native mode technologies to output the graphics and sound of the engine whilst still keeping the engine code entirely in JavaScript. Pls advise!

Cheers,
Ken

Comment: "iOS does not let JavaScript control the HTML5 audio tag". But it lets JavaScript control other HTML5 tags?

Comment: I have the exact same question. Did you try running your game inside JavascriptCore? Did it work? How good or bad was it? What about audio?